# cgi-sys is appearing in CSS/JS/Images url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, web, hosting

[image]Hi All, 
I uploaded a new website which working perfect in localhost to the server but when I am trying to test it, it's showing only the data without any CSS or JS or even images.

I tried to check the source code and I found that "cgi-sys" has been automatically added to all urls.

Any solution for that? could you advise?

Comment: Probably a good question for the hosting provider.

Comment: @mkaatman, I have dedicated server and I change the settings to fix this issue but I don't know how to fix it this is why I placed my question.

Comment: @mkaatman ive never seen godaddy do this before

Comment: hi, is your problem fixed? else please provide a link to your website

Comment: @AnkitDixit, unfortunately not yet you can check link http://pyramisperfume.com/

Comment: @Mhd.Jarkas is there anything in your .htaccess file?